# Aliases and Java

Tags: java

I'm struggling with visualizing why this code would return what it returns.

```
public class IntObject
{
private int myInt;

public IntObject() { myInt = 0; }
public IntObject(int n) { myInt = n; }
public void increment() { myInt++; }
}
```

Driver file

```
public class IntObjectTest
{
    public static IntObject someMethod(IntObject obj) {
        IntObject ans = obj;
        ans.increment();
        return ans;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
IntObject x = new IntObject(2);
IntObject y = new IntObject(7);
IntObject a = y;
x = someMethod(y);
a = someMethod(x);}
```

In my head, the program is going
a is y
x is y + 1 or a + 1, which in this case is 8
a is x(8) + 1. so then it is 9

When the program ends the values i thought they would be are

x = 8

y = 9

a = 9

but the correct values are all 9. I think I'm having trouble with aliases. Could anyone help me out and explain aliases and how they are working in this code?

Comment: This isn't so much about aliases, as it is about how Java passes-by-value. They all have the same object at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are not *aliases*, they are *references*.

```
IntObject x = new IntObject(2); // <-- 2
IntObject y = new IntObject(7); // <-- 7
IntObject a = y;                // <-- 7
x = someMethod(y);              // <-- 8
a = someMethod(x);              // <-- 9.
```

When you call `someMethod`,

```
IntObject ans = obj; // ans points to obj.
ans.increment(); // same as obj.increment();
return ans;
```

I think you expected

```
IntObject ans = obj.clone(); // ans points to a copy of obj.
ans.increment();             // now it won't modify obj.
return ans;
```

Comment: so at the end are their values not all 9?

Comment: @theruss0n At the end, they're all the same instance. There's only one value and one `Object`. The other instances aren't reachable, and maybe garbage collected. The value of an `Object` is the reference.

Answer (score 0):

you are loosing actual reference of x and a.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
IntObject x = new IntObject(2); // "new" is creating a memory block. lets call it 0x10
IntObject y = new IntObject(7); // another "new" is creating a memory block. lets call it 0x20
IntObject a = y; // here, a = 0x20
x = someMethod(y); //someMethod actually takes an element and give same element. so here, x shows 0x20
a = someMethod(x); //someMethod actually takes an element and give same element. so here, x shows 0x20, then a shows 0x20
// at the and, y does not change anytime. so all objects addressing to 0x20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> someMethod(y) returns y, so x = y;
>
> someMethod(x) returns x, so a = x;
>
> ==>> y = x = a

Comment: If I change one of the variables, does it reflect everything else?

IE: If i set x = 2 will y and a now = 2?

Comment: You cannot set IntObject x = 2. x is a reference of an object and 2 is an interger literal which can only be assigned to a primitive int or similar or an Integer or similar type. But if you assign a new object of type IntObject to x , the other ( y and a) are not effected. You should really read something about Types and Objects and the other basic stuff.